# Adding theme settings via module?

Tags: 8, forms

In Drupal 8, what is the recommended way to add new settings to system_theme_settings form?

I tried using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(), but I can't figure out how to save values for theme settings.

Here is some sample code:

```
function headroomjs_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['headroomjs'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#open' => TRUE,
    '#title' => t('HeadroomJS'),
  ];

  $form['headroomjs']['offset'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Offset'),
    '#description' => t('Offset'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('headroomjs.offset', 'testtheme'),
  ];
}
```

I tried referencing the core system_theme_settings form to see how they did it, but can't quite figure it out. I just want to piggyback this module configuration per theme.

Comment: have you set the headroomjs.offset in your theme.yml file?

Comment: I think you will have to do a custom saving/loading because every theme(basically) uses the theme_settings config type. For example see the seven.schema.yml file and code of the theme_get_setting.

Comment: I completely forgot about the theme.yml file.